# PostgreSQL install in 5432 port

Tags: postgresql, centos

I can not setup my PostgreSQL into 5432 port. It always suggest me to 5434 port in centOS-7 operating system. I can not remove 5432 or 5433 port items from my system.
a. How can i see 5432 and 5433 port items from my system ?
b. How can i remove my 5432 and 5433 port items from my system ?
c. Is it is harmful to setup PostgreSQL into 5434 port ?

Comment: `netstat - an` - look for `LISTEN`.

Comment: you can setup PostgreSQL at 5434. It's perfectly fine. But you will need to specify the port for every Postgres utility like psql, pg_dump, pg_restore etc.

Comment: "Laurenz Albe" sorry i can not understand your command...